# Hibernate - lazy load and update single object from the db

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I was lately working on optimizing my application performance, and I noticed that when I lazy load a dependency with MazyToOne relationship, object that hibernate provides is not just lazy loads the object itself, but also all of its fields - so, it has made me think if I maybe can use this to my advantage
Let's imagine the situation like this

```
@Transactional
public void updateUserNameToHarry(Long userId){
  User u = dao.findById(userId);
  u.setName("Harry");
}
```

So we have opened a transaction, loaded Harry into our persistence context, and updated his name.
Once the transaction is closed Hibernate will do its magic and update the name of the user entity we have.
But, in this scenario, I don`t really need to parse Harry db row into entity graph, load Harry into application context, and I definitely do not need to do all of this for the eagerly loaded relationships of Harry.

So here is the question - can I avoid this somehow?
Ideally, I would like Harry to be a lazy loaded object that upon calling setName method adds a single update query, that is going to be executed once the transaction commits.

I am currently using Spring boot 2.0 stack, but my question applies to any other versions and approaches to ORM with java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, these options came to my mind:

1 - obvious one - don't load `User` at all, just perform update query yourself (`UPDATE user SET name = 'Harry' WHERE id = :userId`) - number of ways to achieve this, named query, spring method with annotation etc.

2 - there is a [getReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) method in `EntityManager`, it allows you to get `User` proxy with only it's ID filled, unless you perform some actions on it, then the fields are loaded. It's not gonna help with such as simple case as you posted, but if your `User` had relations to other entities, then you could benefit from it - have a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-manager-get-reference), it's a perfect explanation

Comment: BOOM! Thank you Shadov, the getReference solution worked perfectly, I wrote as small unit test and judging  the SQL logs, hibernate never actually loads the entity, if I only update the fields, it generates the update query, just as I wanted, it is not entirely perfect since it generates update that includes all of the entity fields not just the once that I have updated, but still, this is soooo much better.

Comment: Hmm, although you might be right about the fact that hibernate actually does load the entity from the db if any changes applied, here is why think it might be the case, even though there are no SQL logs about it performing such action -  I noticed that it does not log the update query if the field values I set is equivalent to the one saved in the db, and there is no way for hibernate to know this except for actually loading the entity from the db first.